# Salesforce Community User creation - Password Setting

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

This question is related to the post in the below link

[automate creating communities user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787497/automate-creating-communities-user/25609931#25609931)

If the community user can be created with the automated process, how is the password for the user is set?

Generally, If community user is created, an email will be sent to the email id with a set password link and user has to click the link and set the password manually, even after creating the user automatically.

My question, is there a way to automate the password setting also? or can we set the default password while community user creation and then override the password using the System class method named 'SetPassword' for the community user?

Thanks

Comment: I have searched and not found a way to bulk create passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If you want control over user passwords you will need to set up some sort of delegated authentication.
[This article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/06/how-to-provision-salesforce-communities-users.html) on the dev forum has many details about provisioning community users.  [This blog post](http://www.blacktabgroup.com/keeping-tabs/posts/2013/january/importing-new-user-records-overview-of-the-required-fields.aspx) has details on required fields.  [Info from SFDC on SSO.](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com)